# setup script with node and expresss cluster

Tags: node.js, express, cluster-computing, high-availability

I have a node express server running in a cluster.

I have the need to run initialization script that loads stuff to DB and configure third party. This script should run once.

Given that I don't want to split my server startup to two phases (configure using one node, and then startup all nodes) - How do I call this part of code from only one of my nodes? Is there a common name for such process (bootstrap? because I couldn't find the right keywords to search for it...)

I am using node+express+mongo

Comment: Not sure about your setup but if you're using `npm` to start your cluster you could use a `prestart` [script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)

Comment: but how can I assure that only one node will run this scripts and then others would skip it?

Answer (score 0):

try doing this:

install mongoose (npm install mongoose)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/userData', {useNewUrlParser: true});

//connection

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error',console.error.bind(console,'connectio error'))
db.on('open',function connected(){
    console.log('Good to go!')
    

});

//schema

const userData = 
{
    var : String,
    var1    : String,
    var2 : String
}

const User = mongoose.model("User",userData);

//export

module.exports.User = User;
```

in your server.js file do

```
const { User } = require('./db');`
```